# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘ in JSON at position 0

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I was trying to claim the staked $Aurora rewards with NEAR-CLI by following this [medium article](https://medium.com/near-devs/how-to-claim-your-aurora-reward-from-s-a04c9218614) but when I run the command:

`NEAR_ENV=mainnet near call aaaaaa20d9e0e2461697782ef11675f668207961.factory.bridge.near storage_deposit ‘’ --accountId bailey12.near --amount 0.0125`

The terminal displayed:

```
An error occured
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘ in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at scheduleFunctionCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/commands/call.js:54:84)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.handler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘ in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at scheduleFunctionCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/commands/call.js:54:84)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.handler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9)
```

Any idea how to recorrect this? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper single quote ' instead of ’

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: Better to point out typos in comments rather than answers -- adding an answer that gets upvoted prevents a low-rep OP from deleting their own question, even when that question is off-topic (in this case, being caused by a typographic error).

Comment: I think it is still worth keeping this answer since it has an error that is easy to search on the internet, and so someone can actually benefit from having this answer available.